# Get all generated route points (of lines) to check if you hear route deviation - Leaflet Js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web, leaflet, openstreetmap

I create the route using Leaflet to plot the generated route on the map.

```
var route = L.Routing.Control({
    waypoints: receivedWaypoints,
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    fitSelectedRoutes: true,
    router: new L.Routing.orsmv1({language: 'pt-br', profile: 'car'}),
}).addTo(map);
```

I need to get the route points, so that every X seconds I check if the vehicle is within the route, if not, check the distance from the point where it is from the points closest to the route initially generated to check if it is outside the limit de-route allowed.

I want to receive the coordinates of each point of the entire route, for example: if it contains 3 lines -> A _/\ B, I want to get the coordinates of each end of those lines. being that I only passed two points the beginning of the route and the end of the route

Is there a way to get these points in Leaflet, if so how do I do it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

To get each point of the generated route, after generating the route with the code above, you must add the following lines in the code:

```
route.on('routeselected', function(e){
    //So I return all latitudes and longitudes, pay attention to the size of the array that was generated.
    var allPositions = route._selectedRoute.coordinates;
});
```

Comment: With *route points* you mean coordinates of the user?

Comment: Yes, I want to receive the coordinates of each point of the entire route, for example:
if it contains 4 lines -> A _/\/ B, I want to get the coordinates of each end of those lines. being that I only passed two points the beginning of the route and the end of the route.